# BO Webi - Need Variable to Display Null Instead of Default

Tags: business-objects

I am looking for assistance in writing or adding to a variable to display a null (or blank) value instead of a default calculated field. My report uses variables to calculate the time between two date and time variables. Another variable converts the time to hours and minutes. It subtracts the tracking date/time from the EKG complete date/time. If the EKG complete date/time does not have a value, a calculated value is used. I'd like to display a blank instead. Please see below screenshot and variables for more details.

[Time Difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5R1.png)

[Read Time Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDU6L.png)

[Default Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVK6p.png)

Comment: It would be better if you would include your formulas as text so we could copy them and suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is flip your condition and *not* specify an **ELSE** for your **IF**.

So this...

> =If(([Time Difference (Door to Read)]) < 0) Then [Time Difference (Door to Read)] Else ...all of your number formatting...

...becomes this...

> =If(([Time Difference (Door to Read)]) >= 0) Then ...all of your number formatting...

I would also recommend not using parentheses in your variable names. It makes deciphering the formulas more difficult.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! This is what the formula looks like now.


=If (([Time Difference (Door to Read)]) >= 0) Then (ToNumber(Substr(FormatNumber([Time Difference (Door to Read)];"00000.00");1 ;5))+":"+FormatNumber((ToNumber(Substr(FormatNumber([Time Difference (Door to Read)];"00000.00");6 ;5))*60);"00"))